# Sending a string from C code to Flask

Tags: python, c, sockets

My server is hosted using Flask. I need to send a string from a C code to a page that is running on flask. I am using the socket programming in C to send data to server. But how do I receive it on the flask page? I tried using SocketIO and flask-sockets but was unable to do it properly. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flask talks HTTP. Write your C code to connect to Flask and send HTTP requests.

[`libcurl`](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/) might be useful to you.

At the Flask end, I think that you need to work through the [documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs) to get an understanding of what Flask does and how to write your web app.

You can send a HTTP GET request with a parameter containing your string. In Flask you can access the GET parameters with the `request` object that is available in your view. The URL might be `http://flaskserver/?string=hi+there`. You can access the string by treating `request` as a dictionary, e.g. `string_from_c = request.get('string')`.

Comment: Thanks..i tried it using libcurl and it works like a charm!